# java.awt.Robot was not working with Java 8

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;

import login.Login;

import autoitx4java.AutoItX;

import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

class LoginChildB extends Login{    
}

public class SeleniumDesktopAppTest {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,AWTException {

                final String[] argsCopy = args;
                String jacobDllVersionToUse;
                if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")){
                    jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x86.dll";
                }
                else {
                    jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
                }

                Thread workerThread = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        LoginChildB.main(argsCopy);
                    }
                };workerThread.start();

                File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
                System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

                AutoItX x = new AutoItX();          

                if(x.winWaitActive("JavaFX Welcome")){
                    Thread.sleep(1000*1);
                    x.send("partha"+"\t");
                    Thread.sleep(1000*1);
                    x.send("sarathi"+"\t");
                    Thread.sleep(1000*1);
                    Robot r = new Robot();
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                }       

            }

            /**
            *
            * Returns if the JVM is 32 or 64 bit version
            */
            public
            static String jvmBitVersion(){
             return System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
            }

}
```

In the above code I am trying to open a JavaFX form(imported through external jar) and give the inputs to the text fields after that pressing the submit button. When I am running this code in Java 7 I don't have any issues. But when I am running this code using Java 8 the submit button was not getting pressed. Seems java.awt.Robot was not compatible with Java 8. Can any one please tell how to resolve this problem?

Comment: what it is `AutoItX`, what methods `winWaitActive` and `send`  do? are you sure window is active when you start robot?  I doubt if java 8 will be released if some functionality will be not be working. Hence i think there are problems somewhere else.

Comment: AutoItX is a API used to build test automation scripts similar like Selenium. The winWaitActive() method will get the control of the active desktop dialog box window running currently on top of the machine OS. Dialog box name will be passed as a parameter of this method. The text's passed in the send() method will be placed in the text boxes available in the dialog box window one by one. Window is active only because I can able to run this successfully using Java 7.

Comment: as your `AutoItX` does not look like native java library, and seems like you using bunch of others things between, my suggestion will be split it into small chunks and test each  of them separately to identify what is not working. also try to hold `enter` little bit longer

Comment: I used space key instead of enter key which resolved the issue.    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

Comment: if you resolved your issue, post answer and accept it